# how can i send operation throught eztz to a contract specific entry point?

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, eztz, micheline

im tryng to send the operation to a deployed contract, this is my function ...

```
eztz.contract
.send(
  "KT18qHvhEZUwiawA8QEURwuK8RGJj184725L",
  keysext.pkh,
  keysext.sk,
  5,
  "RIGHT LEFT UNIT",
  "01000",
  50000,
  10000
)
.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

and all i get is this result ...

```
TypeError: "Expected String"
s eztz.min.js:8
decode eztz.min.js:8
decode eztz.min.js:8
b58cdecode eztz.min.js:8
sign eztz.min.js:8
sendOperation eztz.min.js:8
run es6.promise.js:75
notify es6.promise.js:92
flush _microtask.js:18
```

signcontract.js:25

... any ideia of what might be happening??

this my contract parameters and storage,

```
    parameter
  (or :_entries
     (pair :proposition %_Liq_entry_create_proposition
        (key_hash %destination)
        (mutez %amount))
     (or (unit %_Liq_entry_sign_proposition) (unit %_Liq_entry_execute_proposition)));
storage
  (pair :storage
     (set %owners address)
     (pair (set %owners_signed address)
           (option %last_proposition
              (pair :proposition (key_hash %destination) (mutez %amount)))));
```

and the entry point i want to call is the sign_proposition

Comment: Probably the fee ("0100") that is causing the problem.

Comment: i tried changing it to ("1") and i got the same error @Klassare

Comment: and if i put it like this ' "1" ' i get.. Failed to parse the request body: No case matched: Unhandled error (Invalid_argument "Z.of_substring_base: invalid digit") @Klassare

Comment: In that case it's probably keysext.sk that is the problem. I assume that's the private key and the function expects a key pair. So, if you change that to just keysext instead?

Comment: im extracting the keys so i get the pk sk pkh all in one object, @Klassare how should i put them then, create a new object with the pkh and sk ?

Comment: No need to extract it. Just pass the whole keys object.
```
.send(
  "KT18qHvhEZUwiawA8QEURwuK8RGJj184725L",
  keysext.pkh,
  keysext,
  5,
  "RIGHT LEFT UNIT",
 1000,
  50000,
  10000
)
```

Comment: It worked o.o Your are a life saver (it says operation failed but thats my fault, i must have made mistakes on the contract writting), thanks @Klassare

Comment: @Klassare im kind of a newb with this stuff can u help me review my contract, i getting operation failed for gas limit exceeded

Comment: That's a much better failure to have :)

Comment: Try to increase the gas limit from 50 000 to something higher, 800 000 is the highest value you can set it to.

Comment: well x) it didnt display operation error but this apeared ... [{"kind":"permanent","id":"proto.003-PsddFKi3.gas_limit_too_high"}] ... should i be worried? @Klassare

Comment: proto.003 is the old protocol. What node are you connecting to?

Comment: local node i created on granary @Klassare

Comment: Ok, so if you're on the old protocol you can't set the gas limit to more than 400 000.

Comment: proto.003-PsddFKi3.invalidPrimitiveNamespaceTypeError, proto.003-PsddFKi3.invalidConstantTypeError, proto.003-PsddFKi3.badContractParameter ... im screwed right @Klassare

Comment: do u want me to send u the contract? @Klassare (And thanks for all the help :) )

Comment: I would call that progress. But not sure if I will be able to help you with troubleshooting the contract. Maybe you can ask that as a new question here on the stack exchange.

Comment: Okey, i will :) Just one more thing u think there is any problem with running the node with the old protocol? @Klassare

Comment: Not a problem unless you need a higher gas limit than 400 000. But in this case it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: i do not :P thanks for all your help is there any way for me to give a good rating or smth? @Klassare

Comment: No need. I'm just happy to help :)

Comment: Btw, looking at the parameter it looks like you are missing parentheses. Could be worth to try something like "(Right (Left Unit))", but not 100% sure.

Comment: i tried and it gave out this [{"kind":"generic","error":"Operation ont54N8GWeKoj9QL94jyeA1s8Q2AV5g1tQLQJ2APQrSMFS3a4Gq rejected by the mempool pre filter"}] @Klassare

Comment: Probably too low fee in that case, increase it to 1000000 or something.

Comment: yes that worked!! :D i found that out too i was just tryn to figure out which value to input x)

Comment: I just created an answer in the other question that i created and tagged u on it (if u want to check it out i would be most thankful) :) @Klassare

Comment: That's perfect! Will hopefully be useful for someone else. Sometimes a discussion is needed to find the answers. :)

Comment: @Klassare can you please post an answer to the question ? 20 comments is too long so either we have an answer or i need to move this comments into a chat. thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95829/discussion-on-question-by-eduardo-almeida-how-can-i-send-operation-throught-eztz).

Comment: Yes, this discussion became way too long. I edited the answer to give some more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting an answer from the comments (kudos to @Klassare)

- That the private key (keysext.sk) is passed as an argument when eztz expects a keys object (keys = {pkh: string, sk: string, pk: string}) is one problem. Just pass the whole keys object instead. `eztz.contract.send( "KT18qHvhEZUwiawA8QEURwuK8RGJj184725L", keysext.pkh, keysext, 5, "RIGHT LEFT UNIT", 1000, 50000, 10000 )`
- looking at the parameter it looks like you are missing parentheses. Could be worth to try something like "(Right (Left Unit))".
- Try to increase the gas limit from 50 000 to something higher, 800 000 is the highest value you can set it to.
- Try increase the fees to 1000000 or something

`.send( "KT18qHvhEZUwiawA8QEURwuK8RGJj184725L", keysext.pkh, keysext, 5, "(RIGHT (LEFT UNIT))", 1000000, 400000, 10000 )`

Gas limit, storage limit and the fee is not optimized now. You should tweak this values before interacting with this contract on the mainnet. You can do so by doing a simulation (dry-run) or a preapply.