# Getting errors related to the smart contract after running eztz.contract.send()

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, eztz, micheline

im tryng to send a operation to a previously deployed contract and im geting these errors,

```
    error: "Operation Failed"
​
errors: (3) […]
​​
0: {…}
​​​
contract: "KT18qHvhEZUwiawA8QEURwuK8RGJj184725L"
​​​
id: "proto.003-PsddFKi3.badContractParameter"
​​​
kind: "permanent"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
1: {…}
​​​
expectedType: Object { prim: "or", args: (2) […], annots: (1) […] }
​​​
id: "proto.003-PsddFKi3.invalidConstantTypeError"
​​​
kind: "permanent"
​​​
location: 0
​​​
wrongExpression: Object { prim: "RIGHT", args: (2) […] }
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
2: {…}
​​​
expectedNamespace: "constant"
​​​
id: "proto.003-PsddFKi3.invalidPrimitiveNamespaceTypeError"
​​​
kind: "permanent"
​​​
location: 0
​​​
primitiveName: "RIGHT"
​​​
wrongNamespace: "instruction"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
length: 3
​​
<prototype>: [
```

this my contract parameters and storage,

```
    parameter
  (or :_entries
     (pair :proposition %_Liq_entry_create_proposition
        (key_hash %destination)
        (mutez %amount))
     (or (unit %_Liq_entry_sign_proposition) (unit %_Liq_entry_execute_proposition)));
storage
  (pair :storage
     (set %owners address)
     (pair (set %owners_signed address)
           (option %last_proposition
              (pair :proposition (key_hash %destination) (mutez %amount)))));
```

and the entry point i want to call is the sign_proposition, can do u have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This occured because the Michelson in the parameter was ill written and the fee was to low.

So these were the changes i made to the function ...

-Before:

```
eztz.contract
.send(
  "KT18qHvhEZUwiawA8QEURwuK8RGJj184725L",
  "tz1ddb9NMYHZi5UzPdzTZMYQQZoMub195zgv",
  keysextracted,
  5,
  "RIGHT LEFT UNIT",
  1000,
  400000,
  10000
)
```

-After:

```
eztz.contract
    .send(
      "KT18qHvhEZUwiawA8QEURwuK8RGJj184725L",
      "tz1ddb9NMYHZi5UzPdzTZMYQQZoMub195zgv",
      keysextracted,
      5,
      "(Right (Left Unit))",
      1000000,
      400000,
      10000
    )
```

this was also explained to me by @Klassare in

[how can i send operation throught eztz to a contract specific entry point?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1410/how-can-i-send-operation-throught-eztz-to-a-contract-specific-entry-point)